# Is it possible to make roundabout show 5 elements in-front instead of 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-roundabout

I'm using roundabout plugin as a infinite slider that goes round and round. The problem is that I want to show 5 elements in line instead of 3. Is it possible to achieve? Maybe someone tried something like this?

This is what I have so far. http://jsfiddle.net/b9XZf/

```
$(function () {
    $('ul').roundabout({
        minZ: 10,
        maxZ: 30,
        minOpacity: 1,
        minScale: 0.1,
    });
});
```

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 970px;
    height: 350px;
}
li {
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
li img {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}

.monolith{
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 1;
    min-height: 300px;
    min-width: 1200px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: red;
    z-index: 20;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [roundabout-shapes](http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout-shapes)? The shape called "Figure 8" displays 5 items in a line, although the animation is a bit strange.

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('ul').roundabout({
         shape: 'figure8'
      });
   });
</script>
```

[image]

You can also write your own shapes:

```
$(function () {
    jQuery.extend(jQuery.roundaboutShapes, {
        gimmeFive: function(r, a, t) {  
            return {
                // Source: http://smartecharts.aftrix.com/carousel/index.html
                x: (Math.sin(r)>0) ? Math.sin(r/2) : Math.sin(r/2 + Math.PI), 
                y: (Math.sin(r + 3*Math.PI/2 + a) / 8) * t, 
                z: (Math.cos(r + a) + 1) / 2,
                scale: (Math.sin(r + Math.PI/2 + a) / 2) + 0.5                
            };
        }
    });

    $('ul').roundabout({
        minZ: 19, // This value puts the 6th item behind the red <div> 
        maxZ: 30,
        minOpacity: 1,
        minScale: 0.1,
        shape: 'gimmeFive'
    });
});
```

Result:

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/koldev/mYxBA/

Comment: Yeah I tried that. The animation was the problem. It's very weird.